# How to use postMessage to push parent window css to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, postmessage

How can I use postMessage to grab the stylesheet from the parent page, and use it on the page within an iframe?

I'm currently using this jquery to do so, but only works if both pages are on the same domain:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.iframe-div').load(function () {
        $(this)
            .contents().find("head")
            .append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">')
            .append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.url.com/css/font.css">');
    });
});
```

Using `postMessage`, I would have something similar to this on the **index.html** page:

```
var targetOrigin = "http://localhost/";
document.getElementById("#iframe-div").contentWindow.postMessage("#AAAAAA",targetOrigin);
```

but I'm not sure what to do with the  page in the  **iframe**